# Unable to show previously hidden image in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, prototype

Image , with `id = "mobile_right_folder_image"` in HTML is expected to be hidden on start up. On event the image should be visible.

Image is hidden using inline `display:none` and trying to display image in a Javascript function, using the id of the image. Using prototype - AJAX in application.

I have tried display , visibility attribute in javascript nothing seems to be helping. I have a similar image in different location which works fine.

Am suspecting some property of the parent is not letting the image child to be displayed. Please help.

```
HTML Code structure below :


<div id="mc_div_main">
<div id="mc_div_folders_container" style="width: 144px; display: none;">
    <div id="mc_div_content" style="left: 0px;" name="mc_div_content">
        <div id="mc_div_report" class="content" style="display: none" name="content_div"> </div>
        <div id="mc_div_compose" class="content" style="display: none" name="content_div"> </div>
        <div id="mc_div_message_list" class="content" name="content_div">
            <div id="rs_container" class="tile_container" style="overflow: hidden">
                <div class="tile_title_bar">
                        <img id="mobile_right_folder_image" border="0" onclick="javascript:f_folderVSMsgDisplay('1');" style="vertical-align: middle; height: 16px; padding-left: 2px; display:none" src="images/col_chooser_right.gif">
                    <span class="shadow">
                    <span class="tile_header_widgets" style="text-align: right; margin-right: 8px;">
                </div>
            <div id="rs_document" style="height: 150px;">
            <p> </p>
        <div id="rs_separator" class="separator" style="top: 172px;"> </div>
        <div id="rs_calendar" style="bottom: 0px; overflow: auto; top: 178px;">     
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>



Java script :

         document.getElementById('mobile_right_folder_image').style.display='';
```

I have also tried `inline` & `bloc` attribute for display.

---

Better html tree structure as below : (mc_div_folders_container , mc_div_content are siblings at same level)

CHILD -> PARENT path
image : mobile_right_folder_image ->  ->

Am suspecting :  style="overflow: hidden"

```
<div id="mc_div_main">
    <div id="mc_div_folders_container" style="width: 144px;">
        <div id="mc_div_folders" style="bottom: 0px;">
        <div id="mc_folders_separator" class="separator" style="height: 6px; width: 100%; postion: absolute; z-index: 1; height: 407; display: none;"> </div>
        <div id="mc_div_content_selector" style="display: none; overflow: hidden;">
    </div>
    <div id="mc_div_content" style="left: 150px;" name="mc_div_content">
        <div id="mc_div_report" class="content" style="display: none" name="content_div"> </div>
        <div id="mc_div_compose" class="content" style="display: none" name="content_div"> </div>
        <div id="mc_div_message_list" class="content" name="content_div">
        <div id="rs_container" class="tile_container" style="overflow: hidden">
            <div class="tile_title_bar">
                <img id="mobile_right_folder_image" border="0" onclick="javascript:f_folderVSMsgDisplay('1');" style="vertical-align: middle; height: 16px; padding-left: 2px; display:none" src="images/col_chooser_right.gif">
                <span class="shadow">
                <span class="tile_header_widgets" style="text-align: right; margin-right: 8px;">
            </div>
            <div id="rs_document" style="height: 150px;">
            <p> </p>
            <div id="rs_separator" class="separator" style="top: 172px;"> </div>
            <div id="rs_calendar" style="bottom: 0px; overflow: auto; top: 178px;">
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: check html after javascript function completes, see if image has display:none style. I think styles of parent elements are affecting

Comment: set the display to a real css value, such as "none" nor "inline" or "block"

Comment: not sure but there could be overlapping conflicts if you have an inline style there.  try using !important in JS or move the inline style to CSS files

Answer (score 0):

When using Prototype, use `$('mobile_right_folder_image').show()`

Comment: I tried prototype .show() , its not helping to show the image. Also tried update() also with a new image but did not work.

Answer (score 0):

`mc_div_folders_container` is hidden so all of its descendants (the image is a descendant) will not be visible regardless of their style.

```
document.getElementById('mc_div_folders_container').style.display='inline-block';
document.getElementById('mobile_right_folder_image').style.display='block';
```

Comment: Better html tree structure as below :

Comment: @ Musa, Thank you for quick response. Just updated the main question with better HTML tree.